# How to suppress lint on specific line/string in resources xml files?

Tags: android, xml, translation, lint, suppress

On Android, I would like to suppress lint on a specific string value or specific line on a string.xml or other resources files.

```
<string name="suppress_lint_string">Suppress this String</string>

<string name="dont_suppress_lint_string">Don\'t Suppress this String</string>
```

I would like to perform specific lint suppressing on specific strings and specific parts of layouts for examples like missing translations for specific strings that doesn't really matter between languages.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to suppress specific rules in specific strings without suppressing the whole file, you can use annotations.

*strings.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>    

    <!--suppress MissingTranslation -->
    <string name="suppress_lint_string">ignore my translation</string>
    ...

</resources>
```

You can substitute MissingTranslation with any other lint rule.

http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/suppressing-lint-warnings

Comment: Thank you for this. Note, though, that the suppression is accomplished in this case using a comment rather than an annotation.

Comment: You'd think that adding  tools:ignore="PluralsCandidate" to the <string> tag would work too but it doesn't :-P

Comment: Note that you will have to prefix the lint rule with 'AndroidLint'. So in case of suppressing an unused string resource, add: `<!--suppress AndroidLintUnusedResources -->`

Comment: Found that it should not be space between `<!--` and `suppress`.
`<!-- suppress` - wrong
`<!--suppress` - correct

Comment: How can this be achieved in lint.xml, e.g. because my strings.xml is generated?